# Access Web API deserialization/serialization methods within controller body

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to deserialize/serialize JSON `POST` content/response *within* the body of a Web API controller in the same exact way that the controller would deserialize/serialize the `JSON` content/response had it been an argument/explicit type?

My motivation is that I am trying to build a "magic" API controller that can provide access to my service commands quickly if developers do not have enough time to build a strongly-typed action to access them. Say I have the following actions:

```
public Brownie Brownie(BrownieInputModel inputModel)
{
    ...
    var brownie = brownieService.GetBrownie(inputModel);
    return brownie;
}

public Pizza Pizza(PizzaInputModel inputModel)
{
    ...
    var pizza = pizzaService.GetPizza(inputModel);
    return pizza;
}
```

Would it be possible to do something like this (in psuedo-code):

```
public object FoodStuff(string methodName)
{
    var inputModel = WebApi.Deserialize(Request.JsonContent); // <-- pseudo
    var serviceMethod = GetServiceMethodFromMethodName(methodName);
    var result = serviceMethod.Execute();
    return WebApi.Serialize(result); // <-- pseudo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [`HttpRequestMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and [`HttpResponseMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) classes can help you solve this problem. Using them you code can look like that:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(
    string methodName, HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    switch (methodName)
    {
        case "brownie":
            response = await HandleBrownieAsync(request);
            break;
        case "pizza":
            response = await HandlePizzaAsync(request);
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
    return response;
}

private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HandleBrownieAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var brownie = await GetRequestContentAsync<Brownie>(request);
    return await CreateJsonResponseAsync(brownie);
}

private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HandlePizzaAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var pizza = await GetRequestContentAsync<Pizza>(request);
    return await CreateJsonResponseAsync(pizza);
}

private async Task<T> GetRequestContentAsync<T>(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var contentString = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<T>(contentString);
}

private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateJsonResponseAsync<T>(T content)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new StringContent(
            await JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync(content),
            Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/json")
    };
    return response;
}
```

And if you use these simplified models:

```
public class Brownie
{
    public bool HasNuts { get; set; }
}

public class Pizza
{
    public string CheeseType { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can make POST requests:

**URL**: `http://api.url?methodName=brownie`,
**Body**: `{"hasNuts":true}`

or

**URL**: `http://api.url?methodName=pizza`,
**Body**: `{"cheeseType":"Mozzarella"}`